# How to add ripple effect to Preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have an PreferenceFragemnt and I want to have a costum ripple effect on the Preferences. So I started making a CostumPreference but I don't know how to set the background drawable. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123586/how-to-add-ripple-effect-to-preferences-in-android).But this doesn't work for me.

There's my CostumPreference:

```
public class RipPreference extends Preference {
    private Context ctx;

    public RipPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        ctx = context;
    }

    public RipPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ctx = context;
    }

    //This event won't be tiggered
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        //Preference is not an View so there is no onCreateView
        View view = super.onCreateView(parent);
        view.setBackground(<my ripple>);
        return view;
    }
}

    private void setCustomStyle(View view) {
        RippleDrawable drawable = (RippleDrawable) ctx.getDrawable(R.drawable.settings_preference_background);
        view.setBackground(drawable);
    }
}
```

Maybe someone has another idea. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the post you linked to they use the method [onBindView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#onBindView(android.view.View)), not `onCreateView`.

So you could try that:

```
@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);
    view.setBackground(<my ripple>);
}
```

---

Edit: The androidx Preference library uses a recycler view and the method to bind views is called [onBindViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/Preference.html#onBindViewHolder(androidx.preference.PreferenceViewHolder)):

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
    holder.itemView.setBackground(<my ripple>);
}
```

Comment: The problem is the Superclass doesn't have onBindView so it won't be tiggered as well.

Comment: What *is* your superclass exactly? I've added an example for the androidx preference library also

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that.